# refresh jwt token laravel and angularJs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im trying to refresh the token after it has expired but im really lost.Could someone provide an example for me?Also after i used entrust filter to limit my routes based on user role im getting different error messages, before`{"error":"token_expired"}`,now`(TokenExpiredException in PayloadValidator.php line 74:Token has expired)`.

i use typical authentication by the jwt docs:

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }             

    return response()->json(compact('user'));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just managed to solve this issue. Here's how:

In the same controller as the `getAuthenticatedUser()` and `authenticate()` methods reside, I put a token refresh method:

```
public function refresh(Request $request)
{
    try {

        $current_token = $request->get('token');
        //$current_token = JWTAuth::getToken();
        if(!$current_token) return response()->json(null);

        $token = JWTAuth::refresh($current_token);
        return response()->json(compact('token'));

    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } else if ($e instanceof TokenBlacklistedException) {
            return response()->json(['token_blacklisted'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } else if ($e instanceof TokenInvalidException) {
            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } else if ($e instanceof PayloadException) {
            return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
        } else if ($e instanceof JWTException) {
            return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
    }
}
```

And the corresponding route:

```
Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
Route::post('refresh', 'AuthenticateController@refresh'); // The new route.
```

Now, since we're using AngularJS for our frontend and all the HTTP requests, we're determining whether the token has expired from there. Not sure if this applies to your project but maybe you can use the logic principle.

**If you're not using AngularJS for your frontend and is not interested in our frontend logic, which is built in AngularJS, you can stop reading now.**

In our main AngularJS file, `app.js`, where we use `UI-Router` for state-based routing (and the `jwtHelper-library`):

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state jwtHelper, AuthFactory) {

    // Checks if the token has expired on every view change.
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(e, to) {
        if (to.data.requiresLogin && jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(store.get('token')) {
            AuthFactory.attemptRefreshToken();
        }
    });
});

// We use a http interceptor to listen for the Token Expired-exception 
// coming from the backend (Laravel 5.1 and JWTAuth) on any http calls performed.
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('httpInterceptor');
});

// The actual interceptor.
app.factory('httpInterceptor', function ($q, store, $injector) {
    return {

        // On every request that returns an error, check if the status code is 
        // 401 ('unauthorized'), which means the token has expired.
        responseError: function(response) {
            if (response.status == 401){
                var AuthFactory = $injector.get('AuthFactory');

                // Pass the attempted response config in order to retry the request after the refresh.
                return AuthFactory.attemptRefreshToken(response.config);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

And last but not least, our actual refresh call which is stored in our AuthFactory file:

```
attemptRefreshToken: function(requestTodoWhenDone){
    var token = store.get('token');
    return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            skipAuthorization: true,
            url: ApiEndpoint.url + 'refresh',
            data: {token: token}
        })
        .success(function(response)
        {
            // Set the refreshed token.
            store.set('token', response.token);
        })
        .then(function(){

            // Attempt to retry the request if request config is passed.
            if(!angular.isUndefined(requestTodoWhenDone) && requestTodoWhenDone.length > 0)
            {
                // Set the new token for the authorization header.
                requestTodoWhenDone.headers = {
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + store.get('token')
                };

                // Run the request again.
                return $http(requestTodoWhenDone);
            }
        });
});
```

Comment: it actually works but i have a problem where my new token is blacklisted,i have almost the same setup as you have i just use satellizer to sent tokens and i store them in localstorage.

Comment: Right, we noticed this pretty soon. We did the following after my answer:
- We had to catch blacklisted tokens as an exception in the backend in order to make Angular detect if the token is blacklisted or not. 
- We also moved the HTTP-request from the factory to the main app.js because of some bug I'm not familiar with.
- We send the token as a request parameter instead of using JWT's built in auth.

See my updated answer.